# Convert number values into ascii characters?

Tags: python, ascii, chr

The part where I need to go from the number values I obtained to characters to spell out a word it not working, it says I need to use an integer for the last part?

accept string

```
print "This program reduces and decodes a coded message and determines if it is a palindrome"
string=(str(raw_input("The code is:")))
```

change it to lower case

```
string_lowercase=string.lower()
print "lower case string is:", string_lowercase
```

strip special characters

```
specialcharacters="1234567890~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\:;'<,>.?/"

for char in specialcharacters:
    string_lowercase=string_lowercase.replace(char,"")

print "With the specials stripped out the string is:", string_lowercase
```

input offset

```
offset=(int(raw_input("enter offset:")))
```

conversion of text to ASCII code

```
result=[]
for i in string_lowercase:
    code=ord(i)
    result.append([code-offset])
```

conversion from ASCII code to text

```
text=''.join(chr(i) for i in result)
print "The decoded string is:", text.format(chr(result))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Also, for the "strip special characters" part, I would have gone for `string_lowercase = [x for x in string_lowercase in x in string.ascii_letters]`, assuming you used `import string` earlier. Finally, do not name your variable `string`.

Comment: **"The part [...] not working"**. Which part is that, and why are you showing us so many other parts as well, confusing me about where the problem is? Better just show and ask about the first part that does something wrong. (The later parts might only do something wrong because they get already wrong data.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a list of lists instead of a list of ints when you call `result.append([code-offset])`. This means later when you call `chr(i) for i in result`, you are passing a list instead of an int to `chr()`.

Try changing this to `result.append(code-offset)`.

Other small suggestions:

- [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) already gives you a string, so there's no need to explicitly cast it.
- Your removal of special characters can be more efficiently written as:

  ```
  special_characters = '1234567890~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\:;'<,>.?/'
  string_lowercase = ''.join(c for c in string_lowercase if string not in special_characters)
  ```

  This allows you to only have to iterate through `string_lowercase` once instead of per character in `special_characters`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list to `chr` when it only accepts integers. Try `result.append(code-offset)`. `[code-offset]` is a one-item list.

Specifically, instead of:

```
result=[]
for i in string_lowercase:
    code=ord(i)
    result.append([code-offset])
```

use:

```
result=[]
for i in string_lowercase:
    code=ord(i)
    result.append(code-offset)
```

If you understand list comprehension, this works too: `result = [ord(i)-offset for i in string_lowercase]`

Answer (score 0):

While doing `.append()` to list, use `code-offset` instead of `[code-offset]`. As in later you are storing the value as a list (of one ASCII) instead of storing the ASCII value directly.

Hence your code should be:

```
result = []
for i in string_lowercase:
    code = ord(i)
    result.append(code-offset)
```

However you may simplified this code as:

```
result = [ord(ch)-offset for ch in string_lowercase]
```

You may even further simplify your code. The one line to get decoded string will be:

```
decoded_string = ''.join(chr(ord(ch)-offset) for ch in string_lowercase)
```

**Example** with offset as 2:

```
>>> string_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> offset = 2
>>> decoded_string = ''.join(chr(ord(ch)-offset) for ch in string_lowercase)
>>> decoded_string
'_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx'
```